# Oracle BI Publisher and Oracle MCS

Tags: bi-publisher, mcs

Is there anyway to connect Oracle BI Publisher from Oracle MCS Connector Api ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can't say I know anything about Oracle BI Publisher, but if it supports REST or SOAP APIs, then the associated MCS REST or SOAP Connector will be able to call it.

Comment: Thanks for that :)